# Custom Data class lifecycle

Tags: c#, webforms, ienumerable, viewstate

I'm new to web-developing and I'm trying to read a csv file and create a report in Word.I use webform. Code below is my to load file. records is IEnumerable.

```
        if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUploader.PostedFile.FileName).Equals(".csv"))
        {
            CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(File.OpenText(FileUploader.PostedFile.FileName));
            records = csv.GetRecords<T>().ToList();
        }
```

How can I save "IEnumerable" records throughout the page lifecycle? records is empty on PostBack and I don't want to save it in ViewState. 
Thanks

Comment: If you don't want so save it in viewstate how about Session?

Comment: Hi Rene, I didn't want to use session either for performance.  Is there any other efficient way to handle?

Comment: Your only option in that case is to store the PostedFile on disk and recreate the IEnumerable on each postback while keeping track how far you were in the IEnumerable (and thus skipping rercords) or other mechanisms based on your exact requirements.

Comment: Thanks Rene. I will try implementing this.